# Stop method parameter names from being highlighted in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, methods, parameters, android-studio-3.1.3

I have a really annoying problem with the methods in my projects. 
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnWAg.png) you can see what i mean... it's really hard to see and I would prefer that the name would not show at all or at least be more subtle. I looked all over the settings in AS 3.1.3 and I'm also using Java 1.8

[image]

Anyone has any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Disable "Show Parameter name hints" from

`Settings -> Editor -> General -> Appearance -> Unckeck "Show Parameter name hints" -> Apply` as follows:

[image: show parameter name]

Answer (score 2):

You can customise the default colour scheme for the parameter hints by going to:

**Android Preferences** → **Editor** → **Color Scheme** → **Language Defaults**

And select **Inline Parameter hint** and then customise the **foreground** and **background** color scheme as per your choice.

[image]

Also check : [Type hint colors customization](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000004084-Type-hint-colors-customization?page=1#community_comment_115000163670)